# How to link to the attachments added from the description of a workitem? in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-boards

In VSTS attachment can be uploaded for workitems. Those attachments are displayed in a separate tab.

[image]

I found no way to reference those attachments from within the description of the workitems.

So how to do it?

I expected to have attached list in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to manually create that list if you want it. There is no way to have Azure DevOps render the attachments from the attachment tab in the description.